# Stack overflow in GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I faced a stack overflow problem in GDScript.

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmWe.png)

```
(Code to reproduce :)

extends Node
class_name MatchSession

func add_child(ch, un=true):
   add_child(ch, un)
   if get_child_count() == 2:
      _start_match_session()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  While I don't know anything about Godot nor gdscript, the possible reason why you're getting a stack overflow is because you're infinitely recursing into add_child().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `add_child` calls `add_child` recursively, no stop condition:

```
func add_child(ch, un=true):
   add_child(ch, un) # <--
   if get_child_count() == 2:
      _start_match_session()
```

Note also that [`Node.add_child`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child) is not virtual. You are shadowing it. I suggest pick another name for your function.

Comment: can i call with dot ` .add_child(ch, un) ` ? and keep my override of Nodes add_child() method?

Comment: @Aspirational that should work. However, I must reiterate that `add_child` is not virtual (edit: and thus this is not an override). If some other code tries to call `add_child` without the proper type, it will call `Node.add_child`. Similarly, Godot will not call your `add_child`.